# Number of names in data.frame R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame:

in

```
DeviceName                SessionLength
samsung SM-A500FU         6168
samsung SM-A500FU         16199
iPad3,3                   5447
Sony C6602                13838
Iriver tolino tab 7       13657
iPhone6,2                 13434
samsung SAMSUNG-SGH-I317  13292
....
```

I need to get table where I can see numbers of repeat DeviceName.

out

```
DeviceName                NumOfRepeat
samsung SM-A500FU         2
iPad3,3                   1
Sony C6602                1
Iriver tolino tab 7       1
iPhone6,2                 1
samsung SAMSUNG-SGH-I317  1
....
```

Many THX for helping me. 
P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: I think you need `table` i.e. `as.data.frame(table(df$DeviceName))`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

```
Devices<-unique(phones$DeviceName)

NumOfRepeat =rep(0, length(Devices))


for
(i in 1:NumOfRepeat)
{
NumOfRepeat[i] =sum(phones$DeviceName == Devices [i])
}

Data<-data.frame(Devices,NumOfRepeat)
```

[source](http://gastonsanchez.com/Handling_and_Processing_Strings_in_R.pdf)